# How to create empty UUID in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I want to create an empty UUID or UUID for null value in order to insert to PostgreSQL from my application. How can I do it in vue js?

Comment: What do you mean by "empty UUID" exactly?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.